# Define $K$ the index set of $G=\left \{ 1,2,...,n \: |\:n\in \mathbb{N}_0,|G|\geq 100 \right \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Lets define set *G*:
$$G=\left \{ 1,2,...,n \: |\:n\in \mathbb{N}_0,|G|\geq 100 \right \}$$

How to define *K* its index set?

$$K=\left \{ ? \right \}$$

Comment: A priori, sets don't have "index sets" of any kind. You can choose any set $K$ and an "onto" map $g:K\mapsto G$, and then you can call $K$ an index set with that particular map. (Elements/indices $k\in K$ map to $g_k=g(k)\in G$.) I am emphasising "you can choose" - there isn't a preferred way to choose any of those things and you will choose depending on the particular need you have for an index set. Thus my question is: why do you need an index set in the first place?

Comment: I need it to use elements/indices from K to apply a function on values of G

Comment: So may I say that $$K = \left \{ 1,2,...,n \: |\:n\in \mathbb{N}_0, |K|=|G|, g:K \mapsto G   \right \}$$ ?

Comment: Eh ... Of course - you can index every set by itself. ($K$=$G$, $g(k)=k$ for $k\in K$...) Whether that is *useful* depends on the purpose for which you are doing it.